# TextKit doesn't layout text after a wide exclusion path

Tags: ios, textkit

I took the TextKit example project from objc.io #5 http://www.objc.io/issue-5/getting-to-know-textkit.html and modified the width and the form of exclusion path in Text Interaction Demo. I made the exclusion path width more then its container width. And I found that a text doesn't layout after the exclusion path if I place it in the middle of the text. Is there any way to fix it? I want to see the text below the exclusion path. If I add a new text containers I will lost a selection behavior.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this issue yet?

Comment: @JohanKool I've decided to create several text containers and written custom text selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has marked this bug as duplicated.
Rank: 3 - Medium

Comment: This issue has been fixed with the latest (7.1) release of iOS